# How to use quasiqutation with pmap?

Tags: r, rlang

I create a function `f1` to draw a chart passing unquoted variable names from `mtcars`. The below works fine:

```
f1 <- function(dt, title, var) {
  var <- enquo(var)
  ggplot(dt) +
  geom_line(aes(x = mpg, y = !!var)) +
    ggtitle(var)
}
f1(mtcars, var = disp)
```

Now, I would like to iterate using `pmap`. I am trying it on just 1 iteration, but I get the error:

```
pmap(list(data = mtcars, title = disp, var = disp), f1)
>Error in is.data.frame(.l) : object 'disp' not found
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note that your definition of `f1` never uses the argument `title`.)

If you're iterating over multiple columns (e.g., `disp`, `hp`, etc.), one way is to use `rlang::exprs()` to capture unevaluated expressions:

```
l1 <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
l2 <- list("Title", "Not Used")
l3 <- rlang::exprs(disp, hp)

pmap( list(l1,l2,l3), f1 )
```

If you're iterating over multiple data frames, but plotting the same variable, then you can simply pass your expressions as `...` to `pmap`:

```
pmap( list(l1), f1, "My Title", disp )
```

or simply

```
map( l1, f1, "My Title", disp )
```